# Cómo hacer configuración de Android Studio

Tags: android-layout

¿podrian ayudarme.?

¿Que hago yo para que arregle los errores abajo:?
1 - Activity_main
tag tools:contetxt não exihbe la url que se queda en antes de  .MainActivity

2 - Los datos de la activity_main se muestran so[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]lamente cuando se llama el Emulador AVD.

Les dejo la imagen para que revisen.

Muchas gracias a vosotros.

Comment: Es posible que tengas inconvenientes con el renderizado, revisa el archivo build.gradle del app puede que alguna implementación de las librerias de soporte de android no sé este realizando correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por tu contesta. Voy a revisa el archivo buil.gradle del app.
Bonfim desde Brasil

Comment: TheOligarch , he revisado e he visto que el AppTheme está malo.
Entonces cambié el tema ahora está de acuerdo. No lo sé se es algun "bug" de version 3.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución: Use esta versión y eso soluciono el problema (Si quieres usar el tema):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```